# How do i properly do a GET request in react-redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

My goal is to basically do a basic GET request in react-redux. I know how to do it with POST but not with GET because there is no event that is triggering the action.

Heres' the code for action

```
export function getCourses() {
  return (dispatch) => {

    return fetch('/courses', {
      method: 'get',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    }).then((response) => {
      if (response.ok) {
        return response.json().then((json) => {
          dispatch({
            type: 'GET_COURSES',
            courses: json.courses
          });
        })
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Where do i trigger this to get the data? in component?

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getCourses } from '../actions/course';


class Course extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
      this.props.onGetCourses();
  }

  allCourses() {
    console.log(this.props.onGetCourses());
      return this.props.courses.map((course) => {
        return(
          <li>{ course.name }</li>
        );
      });

      return this.props
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          { this.allCourses() }
        </ul>

      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    courses: state.course.courses
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    onGetCourses: () => dispatch(getCourses)
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Course);
```

I tried this but it doesn't work.

Course Reducer

```
const initialState = {
    courses: []
};



export default function course(state= initialState, action) {

  switch (action.type) {
    case 'GET_COURSES':
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        courses: action.courses
      })
    default:
      return state;
  }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `onGetCourses: () => dispatch(getCourses)` should be changed to `onGetCourses: () => dispatch(getCourses())` (you need to actually invoke the action creator).

When it comes to where you should call the action, it is absolutely fine to do it in `componentDidMount`, as you have done.

Answer (score 0):

1. In case you did not notice, you have two return's in your allCourses().
2. I have similar code in my codebase, but I don't use return in front of fetch and response.json() because the function should return action object.